# Latest chromebrowser V 74 is not opening the URL in the new tab

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Chrome Driver(74.0.3729.6) and chrome browser( 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)) for executing the script . When we are launching the browser We are adding the add block plus extension  using chrome options.
when the browser is launched  it is not executing any selenium commands. and it is not showing any error also. could you please let me know how we can resolve it[image]

Chrome Driver(74.0.3729.6)
chrome browser( 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Selenium Version : 3.141.59

```
Code 
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("load-extension=C:\\3.5.2_0");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

I have kept  add block plus extention in the below folder
C:\\3.5.2_0

I opened the addblock plus.js file and made the below value as true 
defaults.suppress_first_run_page = true; so that it will not open the firstrun.html file
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and trace level log messages.

Comment: Hi Debanjan, it seems when we add the add block plus extention with the latest version of  browser. it is not executing any selenium commands. if we manaully click the refresh button it starts to execute it. it is working fine if we are not adding the extention

Comment: Hi Debanjan, I have added my code